# numpy array position of each element along one axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a numpy 2D array, let's say

```
a = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

and I'd like to have an array with the position of each element of this array along one axis like so:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

I need this for the arguments to `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `bar3d`.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What happens if the rows are not sorted? For example if the first row is [3, 2, 1]?

Comment: actually I just need the x position of each element, so the result would be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)

n_rows, n_cols = a.shape
res = np.tile(np.arange(n_cols), (n_rows, 1))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
```